# Data returned from open weather map API not making sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, weather, weather-api

I am using the `Open Weather Map API`. I am still playing around with the calls.  I am having a look at the results of 2 specific calls.  One is for `London` and the other is for `Hermanus` in `South Africa`.  What I observed it that not all data returned in the Hermanus call is in the data returned from the London call.

Here are my 2 calls:

- http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk
- http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hermanus,za

The data returned for London is:

```
{
     "coord": {
          "lon":-0.12574,
          "lat":51.50853
     },
     "sys": {
          "country":"GB",
          "sunrise":1380261352,
          "sunset":1380303998
     },
     "weather": [{
          "id":800,
          "main":"Clear",
          "description":"Sky is Clear",
          "icon":"01d"
     }],
     "base":"gdps stations",
     "main": {
          "temp":290.22,
          "pressure":1016,
          "humidity":63,
          "temp_min":289.15,
          "temp_max":291.48
     },
     "wind": {
          "speed":6.2,
          "deg":100
     },
     "clouds": {
          "all":0
     },
     "dt":1380285272,
     "id":2643743,
     "name":"London",
     "cod":200
}
```

And the data returned for Hermanus is:

```
{
     "coord": {
          "lon":19.234461,
          "lat":-34.418701
     },
     "sys": {
          "country":"ZA",
          "sunrise":1380255856,
          "sunset":1380300203
     },
     "weather": [{
          "id":804,
          "main":"Clouds",
          "description":"overcast clouds",
          "icon":"04d"
     }],
     "base":"gdps stations",
     "main": {
          "temp":284.981,
          "temp_min":284.981,
          "temp_max":284.981,
          "pressure":999.07,
          "sea_level":1026.12,
          "grnd_level":999.07,
          "humidity":77
     },
     "wind": {
          "speed":6.71,
          "deg":282
     },
     "rain": {
          "3h":0
     },
     "clouds": {
          "all":92
     },
     "dt":1380285425,
     "id":3366880,
     "name":"Hermanus",
     "cod":200
}
```

Why does the one contain certain data and the other not?  How can I find out what all can be returned from such a call?  And how do I know what each item means that is returned?

Comment: It's entirely down to the 3rd party what data is returned. It's possible that they do not have a full suite of data for all locations. You'd probably be best requesting information from the data provider themselves.

Comment: Rory is right. I'm having the same problem with their api sometimes not returning rain.3h data and sometimes it being 0. Maybe it's time to check for another api like forecast.io

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this page, you will see that some returned keys are actually optional:

http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/2.0/Weather_Data

Even the obvious `weather` key is optional! :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there perhaps a wiki for version 2.5? Documentation on this API is not that clear.

Comment: @BrendanVogt The weather data has not changed since version 2.0 :)

Comment: @BrendanVogt- Here is the summary of the parameteres used in API 2.5- http://openweathermap.org/weather-data#current